# Run scripts on kusto engine

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am developing an API right now, which fetches data from kusto engine, runs an algorithm on it and returns the result.
I was wondering, if there is a way to run my algorithm on kusto engine only, and then retrieve a tabular result directly. This will avoid the bottleneck of running algorithm in API.
Is there a way to run algorithm on kusto tables and return the resultant table?

E.G.- I am given a graph edge list in form of a kusto table.
Algorithm is to run Disjoint Union Set on it and count total no of connected components. Can this algo be run on kusto engine in some way?

Please suggest me something in this direction if it exists, so that I can explore

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pythonplugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: Btw, according to you, which one is a better and more optimized way?
Running the algorithm on API or running it using the python plugin in Kusto?

Comment: That depends on too many variables. Develop first, decide later.